# How to Generate a csv file in python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, file, csv, generate

I have a problem where I have to fetch the data through API calls using Python.  I have the data.  Now I have to convert it to a csv file.

We do not have to use numpy or panda. We can only use "Import collections" to generate csv file.
I am a beginner in python. Can someone help me with that please?

Comment: Hello and weclome to SO. We cannot help without a clear, focused question. IOW, you'll first have to search the subject, try to solve the problem by yourself, then come with a concrete question.

Comment: Just a hint: neither numpy nor panda are required to create a csv file, specially when there's a `csv` package in the stdlib. Note that if this is homework and you cannot even use the csv package, it's still mostly a matter of basic string formatting file operations. NB: it's ok to ask help on homework, but you must mention it's homework (and understand that the help you will get will not include working code, since doing your homework for you would _not_ actually help you).